# Добавить 3 часа к времени - PHP (увеличить переменную в массиве)

Tags: php, время

Переменной присваивается значение текущего времени (по UTC), что меньше на три часа требуемого местного времени.

```
$time = getdate();
```

В итоге получается массив, с которым дальше работает код javascript. Можно конечно просто прибавить три часа...

```
var hour={$time['hours']};
var hour = hour + 3;
```

Но хотелось бы получить сразу нужное число часа (по МСК, то есть UTC+3)

Comment: `$today = getdate(strtotime('+3 hours'));`

Comment: _что меньше на три часа требуемого местного времени._ Так может вы просто locale будете указывать а не манипулировать временем?

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен.... А как это указать locale? Мне нужно время с сервера, а не с компьютера пользователя.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow"); $time = getdate();`

Comment: Такая команда "ломает" другие плагины, работающие со временем. У меня WordPress. За решение спасибо! Оно подходит